# Vim-pythoncomplete auto-complete

Tags: python, vim

My vim config is in [github.com/liuzheng712/config](http://github.com/liuzheng712/config)
You can re-show my problem with this steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/liuzheng712/config.git --depth=1
cd config     
git submodule init     
git submodule update
```

Then you can `soft-link .vim and .vimrc` to your `$HOME` directory
(Please backup your own .vim and .vimrc files)

After all things are done, when you do `vim test.py` and `input "ihello."`
when you type `"."` the following errors come

```
Error detected while processing function pythoncomplete#Complete:     
line   35:     
Traceback (most recent call last):    
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pythoncomplete#Complete:
line   35:
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pythoncomplete#Complete:
line   35:
File "<string>", line 40, in vimcomplete
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pythoncomplete#Complete:
line   35:
File "<string>", line 221, in get_completions
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pythoncomplete#Complete:
line   35:
NameError: global name 're' is not defined
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pythoncomplete#Complete:
line   36:
E121: Undefined variable: g:pythoncomplete_completions
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function pythoncomplete#Complete:
line   36:
E15: Invalid expression: g:pythoncomplete_completions
```

Can any one solve my problem ? Thanks

Comment: If you need a couple paragraphs to explain how to check out your code repo and create local symlinks, before you can even start to answer the question, then the question needs improved.

Comment: 1. Nobody is going to install your config. 2. Use the plugin's issue tracker. That's what it's made for. 3. `filetype indent on` should come *after* the pathogen line. 4. You seem to have forgotten to define a global variable.

Comment: Also, I think your problem is due to how you source the autoload script from that plugin. Your vimrc is clean and tidy but it's still a mess.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I do this not in one time , so a lot things I also fell a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have more success with [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) instead of pythoncomplete. Vim's omnicomplete for Python suffers from a number of bugs that jedi-vim solves. Pythoncomplete may have been started to solve some of these problems, but the project appears to be abandoned.

Comment: thanks a lot, I already did this before , but did work well , so I delete all vim-python-plugins and only use[Pydiction](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Pydiction) . It works well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also try deoplete-jedi to have a faster auto-complete experience (but still can use other features from jedi-vim).